# Can't "require()" certain core packages?

Tags: ruby

Ruby is screwing with me, it seems. That or RubyMine. So, I've created a class called `NetworkDaemon` and it's associated specification in `NetworkDaemonSpecification`. Pretty simple.

However, my issue is that I can't seem to use `require 'tcp_server'` from `network_daemon.rb`, but I can from `network_daemon_specification.rb`.

If I try and reference `tcp_server` from `network_daemon.rb` (which is unit tested in `network_daemon_specification.rb`, I get the following stacktrace

```
E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- tcp_server (LoadError)
    from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from E:/Ruby/RubyCraft/network/network_daemon.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from E:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'
    from E:/Ruby/RubyCraft/specification/network_daemon_specification.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

However, I can reference `tcp_server` in `network_daemon_specification` just fine. What's going on? D:

`network_daemon.rb`

```
require 'tcp_server'

module RubyCraft
  module Network
    # The network daemon controls the listening and responses
    class NetworkDaemon
      attr_reader :port
      # Creates the NetworkDaemon from the given port
      # @param [Fixnum] port
      def initialize port
        @port = port
        @sock = TCPServer.new @port
      end

      # Closes the NetworkDaemon
      def close
        @sock.close
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`network_daemon_specification.rb`

```
# Unit tests for the Network Daemon that will be used to listen for connections
module RubyCraft
  module Specifications
    class NetworkDaemonSpecification < Test::Unit::TestCase
      def setup
        @port = 9999
        @daemon = NetworkDaemon.new @port
      end

      def test_port_should_equal_injected_port
        assert_equal @daemon.port, @port
      end

      def teardown
        @daemon.close
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `require 'socket'` not `tcp_server`

Check the `TCPServer` documentation for more information http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/TCPServer.html

Comment: RubyMine misled me. ._.

Comment: How do you know that you can require it form the specification file? Are you using that file or loading it when you load your app? If not the require in the specification file will never get run and you'll never see the error.

Comment: Because I loaded it in the specification file and injected an instance of TCPServer just fine into my NetworkDaemon constructor.

Comment: Weird. I don't know what RubyMine would do to load a file that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `tcp_server` is not what you need to require (despite what RubyMine says) - you should require `socket`